# i want to export my products but this notification come "Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon" but nothing happen anything why?

Tags: magento2

when i export my products this notification come ( massage is added in queue wait to get your file) but i don't get file any tell me about it how to get or solve it

Answer (score 0):

You have to run cron by command line as mentioned here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23450#issuecomment-507581035

Then refresh the export page and you should see the file at the bottom.

Comment: If using link as reference to answer, please add relevant bits from it to your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

To get the export file, run the below command. After running this, the file should be displayed in the grid.

php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor